# Create instance of COM class dynamically in .NET

Tags: .net, com, interop

I can load COM DLLs that are registered on my machine like this:

```
Type type = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("MYCOMDLL.ClassName");
object boxed = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
```

I can then poke around invoking methods etc.

How can I achieve this from a DLL file that is not registered on my machine?

Something like this magicode:

```
Type type = Type.GetTypeFromFile("MyFile.dll", "MYCOMDLL.ClassName");
object boxed = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You either have to (a) register the DLL first in the traditional way, or (b) muck about with Registration-Free COM manifest files.

This might help with (b) - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973913.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I found this link which may have what you want:

[Dynamically calling an unmanaged dll from .NET (C#)](http://blogs.msdn.com/jonathanswift/archive/2006/10/03/Dynamically-calling-an-unmanaged-dll-from-.NET-_2800_C_23002900_.aspx)

Looks like you could wrap a helper class around it.

Comment: That works for unmanaged native DLL's, but if it's a COM library it won't.

Comment: Oops, you're right. I looked for alternatives, found a way to load a livrary and retrieve all the COM objects, but the activation itself seems to require the DLL to be registered.